# how to use ckeditor4-angular to save images in the database

Tags: javascript, angular, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor4 in my Angular Application and I want to upload an image onto my server (database) using `easyimage` plugin for this.

According to the documentation, there are two configuration for ckeditor `cloudServices_uploadUrl` and `cloudServices_tokenUrl` which I can't understand that why I need these.

**Is there any way to save images directly into the database by providing API URL?**

Below is the configuration for ckeditor which I'm using:

```
ckEditorConfig = {
  title: '',
  toolbar: [
    { name: 'basicstyles', items: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline'] },
    { name: 'colors', items: ['TextColor', 'BGColor'] },
    { name: 'align', items: ['JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight'] },
    { name: 'paragraph ', items: ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', 'Blockquote', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize'] },
    { name: 'links', items: ['Link', 'Unlink'] },
    { name: 'insert', items: ['EasyImageUpload'] },
    { name: 'clipboard', items: ['Undo', 'Redo'] },
  ],
   height: 'calc(100vh - 340px)',
   maxHeight: 'auto',
   width: 'auto',
   minWidth: '0',
   removeButtons: '',
   extraPlugins: 'format, font, colorbutton, justify, easyimage',
   removePlugins: 'image',
   cloudServices_uploadUrl: 'https://33333.cke-cs.com/easyimage/upload/',
   cloudServices_tokenUrl: 'https://33333.cke-cs.com/token/dev/ijrDsqFix838Gh3wGO3F77FSW94BwcLXprJ4APSp3XQ26xsUHTi0jcb1hoBt',
};
```

Comment: What kind of database? And most likely you can't just pass in database URL, but back-end URL that handles upload. And don't store separate images to DB, but to server storage. As I see [this plugin](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/easyimage) uploads images not to your server, but to [CKEditor Cloud Service](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-cloud-services/)

Comment: @Justinas thanks for your time! I want to save images into my server by hitting an API. I was asking the same in my question above that where to put my back-end URL? OR there is no way to save image onto my server?

Comment: How about [Image Uploader and Browser](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/imageuploader)? There definitely are plugins to upload images to server for CKEditor